# trigger cordova build from remote machine

Tags: cordova

I have a Apache Cordova (3.4) setup in my Windows machine. When I take build using `cordova build android --release` through CLI, it is working fine. I am integrating this setup with my build server like jenkins which is in UNIX box. When I call `cordova build android --release` remotely from jenkins, I am getting the following error

```
Downloading cordova library for android... 
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 
at errnoException (net.js:904:11) 
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

My intention was triggering the build from remote build machine and take the generated APK to bundle.

My question is: why it is trying to download again when Cordova setup is already available?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I reinstalled cordova buy using the command `npm install -g cordova` in my windows slave box.

Now i am not getting `Downloading cordova library for android...` error in my jenkins build box. Build is successful.